# Unresolved reference 'BeautifulSoup' in python 3.7 in anaconda

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, conda

I am using this command to install BeautifulSoup in Mac OS:

```
conda install beautifulsoup4
```

then check the result:

```
$ conda list -e|grep bea
beautifulsoup4=4.9.3=pyhb0f4dca_0
(pydolphin)
```

but in the PyCharm still could not using this package:

[image]

what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is `bs4`, `BeautifulSoup` is a class inside the `bs4` module which you'll import, whether you use `conda` or `pip`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

Comment: can you provide a little more explaination

Comment: In all honestly this one of the answer which doesn't require any explanation. It's like you are looking to buy "black apple" then someone says use "red apple". It's pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem using Pycharm, it was installed but pycharm did not recognize it, in that case a simple right-click on the "Beautifulsoup" and then the option "install package BeautifulSoup" helped for me